# Keeping rotated divs from expanding on page resize

Tags: css, sass, responsive

I have two divs that are rotated and should maintain the same distance as the page expands, as well as not grow. However, as they are currently setup, they expand and the space between them grows. I need them to maintain their distance and width as the page expands and not sure why they aren't as they're currently set:

```
<div class="masthead-wrapper">
  <div class="masthead-two-boxes-angled-wrapper">
    <div class="left">Left</div>
    <div class="right">Right</div>
  </div>
</div>



.masthead-wrapper {
  z-index: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  .masthead-content {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    width: 1172px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .masthead-two-boxes-angled-wrapper {
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    z-index: 0;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    .left {
      width: 45%;
      background-color: #eee;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      top: -20px;
      position: relative;
    }
    .right {
      width: 40%;
      background-color: #eee;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      bottom: 20px;
      position: relative;
      box-shadow: 0 -22px 29px 10px #cecece;
    }
  }
}
```

JSFIDDLE: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/meq31d0x/13/)

Answer (score 0):

They are responding as the screen width changes because your width set on the `.masthead-wrapper` is a percentage. Changing it to a pixel width will prevent the resizing from happening. However, with a pixel width you may have to set up different breakpoints to adjust for how you want the left and right boxes to appear on desktop, tablet, and mobile.

Example:

```
.masthead-wrapper {
    z-index: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

    /* Tablet */
    @media (min-width: 480px) {
        width: 400px;
    }

    /* Desktop */
    @media (min-width: 960px) {
        width: 600px;
    }
}
```

Also, you have a class being styled that is not referenced in the HTML (`.masthead-content`). You can remove this completely unless you need it for some other reason. Hope this helps.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/meq31d0x/25/